# load filtered values in p:dataTable while the page is loading

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

How to load filtered values in the data table while the page is loading?
I have 3 data tables in a single page.

Tried adding filterValue="BMW" in

```
<p:column
    headerText="Car Type"
    sortBy="#{car}"
    filterBy="#{car}" 
filterValue="BMW" id="carTypeColumn">
    <h:outputText id="car"
                  value="#{carResultsRow.car.type}" />
</p:column>
```

---

```
<p:dataTable id="carResults"
value="#{carMB.car}" var="carResultsRow"
rows="20" paginator="true" widgetVar="carResultsVar"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
{PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
style="margin-bottom:20px" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
lazy="true" sortOrder="DESCENDING"
currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
{totalRecords})"
rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
emptyMessage="No results found for search."
reflow="true">

<p:column
    headerText="Car Type"
    sortBy="#{car}"
    filterBy="#{car}" id="carTypeColumn">
    <h:outputText id="car"
                  value="#{carResultsRow.car.type}" />
</p:column> 



<p:dataTable id="carResults2"
value="#{carMB.car}" var="carResultsRow"
rows="20" paginator="true" widgetVar="carResultsVar"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
{PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
style="margin-bottom:20px" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
lazy="true" sortOrder="DESCENDING"
currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
{totalRecords})"
rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
emptyMessage="No results found for search."
reflow="true">

<p:column
    headerText="Car Type"
    sortBy="#{car}"
    filterBy="#{car}" id="carTypeColumn">
    <h:outputText id="car"
                  value="#{carResultsRow.car.type}" />
</p:column> 


<p:dataTable id="carResults3"
value="#{carMB.car}" var="carResultsRow"
rows="20" paginator="true" widgetVar="carResultsVar"
paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} 
{PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
style="margin-bottom:20px" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
lazy="true" sortOrder="DESCENDING"
currentPageReportTemplate="(Displaying {startRecord} - {endRecord} of 
{totalRecords})"
rowStyleClass="#{(rowIndex mod 2) eq 0 ? 'highlight1' : 'highlight2'}"
emptyMessage="No results found for search."
reflow="true">

<p:column
    headerText="Car Type"
    sortBy="#{car}"
    filterBy="#{car}" id="carTypeColumn">
    <h:outputText id="car"
                  value="#{carResultsRow.car.type}" />
</p:column>
```

The following data table produces the result-

**Actual Results**

Data Table 1

```
ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price

adff7ca0    1974    BMW     Blue    Sale    $14,160.00
50f83d04    1998    Renault Silver  Sale    $43,645.00
27b7be8d    1995    Merc    Red     Sold    $80,627.00
b35c4322    2006    BMW     Orange  Sold    $16,051.00
7888e692    1997    Fiat    Red     Sale    $4,508.00
adbf1199    2004    Audi    Brown   Sale    $37,511.00
8eb3e5a9    1985    Honda   Black   Sold    $46,729.00
fed0821c    1990    BMW     Red     Sale    $88,185.00
85d2282f    1967    Honda   Orange  Sold    $33,674.00
bc34ed49    1972    BMW     Blue    Sale    $81,567.00
```

Data Table 2

```
ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price

adff7ca0    1974    BMW     Blue    Sale    $14,160.00
50f83d04    1998    Renault Silver  Sale    $43,645.00
27b7be8d    1995    Merc    Red     Sold    $80,627.00
b35c4322    2006    BMW     Orange  Sold    $16,051.00
7888e692    1997    Fiat    Red     Sale    $4,508.00
adbf1199    2004    Audi    Brown   Sale    $37,511.00
8eb3e5a9    1985    Honda   Black   Sold    $46,729.00
fed0821c    1990    BMW     Red     Sale    $88,185.00
85d2282f    1967    Honda   Orange  Sold    $33,674.00
bc34ed49    1972    BMW     Blue    Sale    $81,567.00
```

Data Table 3

```
ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price

adff7ca0    1974    BMW     Blue    Sale    $14,160.00
50f83d04    1998    Renault Silver  Sale    $43,645.00
27b7be8d    1995    Merc    Red     Sold    $80,627.00
b35c4322    2006    BMW     Orange  Sold    $16,051.00
7888e692    1997    Fiat    Red     Sale    $4,508.00
adbf1199    2004    Audi    Brown   Sale    $37,511.00
8eb3e5a9    1985    Honda   Black   Sold    $46,729.00
fed0821c    1990    BMW     Red     Sale    $88,185.00
85d2282f    1967    Honda   Orange  Sold    $33,674.00
bc34ed49    1972    BMW     Blue    Sale    $81,567.00
```

**Expected Results**

Here in the expected results data tables were filtered by the type of car, First data table was filtered by the type BMW and contains the type BMW,  Second data table was filtered by the type Honda and contains the values of Honda, The third data table contains the type of both Renault and Merc.

Datatable 1

```
ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price 
adff7ca0    1974    BMW     Blue    Sale    $14,160.00  
b35c4322    2006    BMW     Orange  Sold    $16,051.00
fed0821c    1990    BMW     Red     Sale    $88,185.00          
bc34ed49    1972    BMW     Blue    Sale    $81,567.00
```

Datatable 2

```
ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price
85d2282f    1967    Honda   Orange  Sold    $33,674.00
8eb3e5a9    1985    Honda   Black   Sold    $46,729.00
```

Datatable 3

```
ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price
50f83d04    1998    Renault Silver  Sale    $43,645.00
27b7be8d    1995    Merc    Red     Sold    $80,627.00
```

===============================

Result With the solution posted

```
 filterBy="#{carMB.filterBy}"  filterBy = singletonList(new FilterState(

ID          Year    Type   Color  Status    Price
                   BMW -------------- Appeared in the filter header
dff7ca0    1974    BMW     Blue    Sale    $14,160
f83d04    1998    Renault Silver  Sale    $43,640
7be8d    1995    Merc    Red     Sold    $80,627
5c4322    2006    BMW     Orange  Sold    $16,051
88e692    1997    Fiat    Red     Sale    $4,508
bf1199    2004    Audi    Brown   Sale    $37,511
3e5a9    1985    Honda   Black   Sold    $46,729
0821c    1990    BMW     Red     Sale    $88,185
2282f    1967    Honda   Orange  Sold    $33,674
4ed49    1972    BMW     Blue    Sale    $81,567
```

Comment: Use PrimaFaces lazy loading... way more control over things

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your filter works at all when you manually input text, it is still true that the `filterValue` attribute of `p:column` does not seeme to trigger actual data filtering. Instead it only populates the filter input with the bound value. (Not sure if this is intentional)

In order to actually apply a default filtering, you'll have to populate a `java.util.List` with one or more `org.primefaces.component.datatable.FilterState` instances:

```
package my.pkg;

import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.component.datatable.FilterState;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
    private List<FilterState> filterBy;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        filterBy = singletonList(new FilterState("frm1:carResults:column1", "BMW"));
    }

    // getters / setters
}
```

Then bind this list to `p:dataTable#filterBy` attribute:

```
<h:form id="frm1">
    <p:dataTable id="carResults" filterBy="#{myBean.filterBy}" ...>
        <p:column id="column1" ...>
        ...
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Note that columns are identified by their xhtml element IDs.

---

As of **PrimeFaces 8.0** `FilterState` is now named `FilterMeta`.

Comment: I learned something new... not that I'd drop using lazy models and optimusfaces, but never the less... never too old to learn

Comment: @Selaron Hello, I have tried to implement your solution , But the results are not the same as the Expected results.

By your solution 

I get the  Actual Results and BMW   on my  column1  filter Header where the user is forced to hit enter, then the filtered values have started to appear,

Comment: Thank you for your input

Comment: I may have mis represented / presented the issue in a wrong way, Can I please know how to trigger actual data filtering while the page is loading? Thanks

Comment: @keerthi199 hmm that's different from my test case. Possibly you can assign a widgetVar="myTable" to the p:dataTable and in a h:outputScript do: `$(document).ready(function(){PF('myTable').filter();});`

Comment: @Selaron I have tried to implement - <script  type="text/javascript" target="body">
$j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready( function() {
carResultsVar.filter();   
});
</script>    But still unable to load/trigger the filtered values, Any inputs? Thanks

Comment: Did you *try* PF 7? @keerthi199

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer the following might be helpful:

This fires off an additional asynchronous call to the backend to the lazy loading component to filter the items, but since the page has not loaded properly yet, I needed to use the setTimeout to call after the page has loaded and created the PF object

```
    <h:outputScript target="head">
        $(function() {
            setTimeout(function() { PF('myTable').filter(); }, 100);
        });
    </h:outputScript>
```